# Why isn't my SQL Update query working? (the row is not affected)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, sql-update

I am creating a website with ASP.NET using Visual Studio 2019. On a webform, I have some data coming from an SQL table and I want to update it when I click a button. Here is the function that is called when I click the button:

```
void updateUserPersonalDetails()
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE member_master_tbl SET full_name=@full_name, dob=@dob WHERE member_id='" + Session["username"].ToString().Trim() + "'", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@full_name", TextBoxFullName.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", TextBoxDOB.Text.Trim());

        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        if (result > 0)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Details Updated Successfully');</script>");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Invalid entry');</script>");
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "');</script>");
    }
}
```

I get the alert that the details are updated but in reality they are not updated. Other queries like SELECT and INSERT work, so the problem is not with the connection. I tried using Linq to do it but I get the same result.

Comment: Is `member_id` a number or string type in the database? Show the sql query runtime value.

Comment: Please check session parameter value.

Comment: why do you not create a parameter for member_id?

Comment: In addition to the questions above, which are  in the good direction in order to diagnose what's going on, I would suggest  as a *good practice* closing the connection when you get an exception, maybe in the *catch* or even in an *finally* so, you get it always closed.

Comment: A little bit OT, but i would recommend "Session["username"].ToString().Trim()" convert to parameter, e.g. @username - depending on your field type there are a lot of possible issues, e.g. sql injection via username "'or 1=1 ;--"

Comment: I'm betting your update has in fact changed a row in the database, just not the one you were expecting, or not with the values you thought.  Set a breakpoint before the `ExecuteNonQuery()` line, and see what has been set as  member_id, and inspect the cmd.Parameters to verify they're the new values you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 // open the connect via the cmd
cmd.Connection.Open();
 //then execute
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


 //also you want to check for not -1 
 if (result != -1)
  {
     //query ran ok and rows were updated
  }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: How can I check/modify this setting?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-nocount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

I found that it works if I set the value of **full_name** in the sql query like this :

```
UPDATE member_master_tbl SET full_name= 'blabla' WHERE member_id = 'm001'
```

But when I put in a parameter like this it doesn't work :

```
UPDATE member_master_tbl SET full_name= '" + TextBoxFullName.Text + "' WHERE member_id ='m001'
```

The parameter's name is correct. The value type in the database is an nvarchar(50). What am I missing?

Comment: There is no parameter in either version shown... But: is there perhaps a single quote or similar in the text value? That's an example of why you should *use* a parameter

Answer (score -2):

Try adding a data adapter.

Where `int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`
Try this instead

```
result = new SqlDataAdapter(); //<- Put this below your SqlConnection con = ...
result.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

`UPDATE`would need `UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` derived from `SqlDataAdapter` to get or set a Transact-SQL statement or stored procedure used to update records in the data source.

Comment: "A data adapter can work, but it is not necessary" - Does not validate a wrong answer. Where as using int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() is still an invalid type data type for ExecuteNonQuery() command.

Comment: "*int is the wrong datatype here*" - is wrong. "*SELECT and INSERT don't rely on ExecuteNonQuery()*" is wrong. Also, adapters do not have an UpdateCommand by default so your example is wrong.

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of rows affected, and it is an int type. The answer is wrong in the sense that it suggests that using the data adapter would produce different results.

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery(); Has to be executed to update the database.  This is not done by saying int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() you're assigning a value to result, not executing it. Also, SqlDataAdapter does have UpdateCommand property.  Take a look here, straight from the manufacturer. Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.updatecommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude but you are wrong. `int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` will absolutely execute the command in the database. And I know there is an UpdateCommand property, but you have to assign a SqlCommand to it. Your example does not assign one so it cannot succeed.

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude either, and I'm not saying you're wrong.  What I'm saying is in the way he wrote his code the db would update with an ExecuteNonQuery(); Because the UpdateCommand property gets or sets a Transact-SQL statement or stored procedure used to update records in the data source, therefore, by instantiating a new SqlDataAdapter object. My example does not assign an SqlCommand because that is not the issue. UpdateCommand property is from SqlDataAdapter and op was already using SqlCommand correctly.  No UpdateCommand property exists under SqlCommand object which I tried to say.